# property undefined - how to solve

Tags: javascript

I get an error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at VM32939 own.js:819
```

for

```
var hands_corrected = (hands_original.top + 680)
```

and that's correct, as "hands_original" isn't used on any page of my project, so hands_original is then undefined and thereby wrong.

I try to solve it therefore with

```
var hands_corrected = (hands_original.top + 680) || 0;
```

but that still gets me that error. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `hands_original` is an object and it has a key by name `top`.In this case the object `hands_original` seems to be undefined , so it cannot find the key `top`

```
var hands_corrected=hands_original && hands_original.top+680||0;
```

By this code you are checking if `hands_original` is defined, if it is defined then add a num to it the value of it's key top. If `hands_original` is undefined then assign `0` to `hands_corrected` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var hands_corrected = (hands_original && hands_original.top + 680) || 0;
```

Or

```
var hands_corrected = hands_original ? hands_original.top + 680 : 0;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what that does?

Comment: This means, if `hands_original` is not undefined, get the top and add 680. If this result will be number get it else get 0

Comment: Please test code before copy to someone when it's possible... Code returning "SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression" also even with putting : instad of || there is still error "ReferenceError: hands_original is not defined"... And it will work only when hands_original not defined otherwise it can return interesting results...

Comment: I copy from my another variant. Changed

Answer (score 1):

There is two things with what you need to be careful **hands_original** and **hands_original.top** so I perfer to check them both on this way

```
var hands_corrected = (typeof(hands_original) != 'undefined' && typeof(hands_original.top) != 'undefined') ? hands_original.top + 680 : 0;
```

if check only hands_original.top, and hands_original is undefined we will got "ReferenceError: hands_original is not defined" so I suggest to check both like in my code